# How Do I Enable the Paradox Scope?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Some of the fragments I have left to get require the *Paradox Scope* to be enabled. I now have this from when I cleared the main story, but I can't find an option to turn it on. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you have the Fragment Skill (which is obtained in Serendipity, from the Mystic in Temptation Plaza) you should see Paradox Scope in your list of Fragment Skills.

Comment: That's it; I didn't go to Serendipity to pick up the skill. I just assumed it would be active. Thanks!